# Eager load an ionic Toast Controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, offline

I have this function that listen the internet connection

```js
  private verifyNetworkConnection() {
    this.networkService
      .isNetworkConnected
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(connected => {
        if (connected) {
           // do secret things
        } else {
            this.toast.create({
            message: 'Sem conexão a internet',
            showCloseButton: true,
            duration: 2000,
            cssClass: ToastClasses.ERROR
          }).then((res) => res.present());
          this.disconnectFromServices();
        }
      });
  }
```

And in the else block, i need to show a Toast that says the user has no connection, but the toast doenst show, i read some topics saying that the ToastController is lazy loaded and cant load when there is no connection, is there anyway to Eager Load the component to show when there's no connection ??

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it like so: i.e. create a service

*network-state.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Network } from "@ionic-native/network/ngx";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { ShowToastService } from "./show-toast.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NetworkStateService {
  private connectSubscription$: Subscription = null;
  constructor(private network: Network,
    private showToastService: ShowToastService) { }

  WatchConnection() {
    if (this.connectSubscription$) { this.connectSubscription$.unsubscribe(); }
    this.connectSubscription$ = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.showToastService.showToast("Your internet seems to be down! Please check your network settings!",'danger');
      if (this.connectSubscription$) { this.connectSubscription$.unsubscribe(); }
      this.connectSubscription$ = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(async() => {
          this.showToastService.toast.dismiss();
          if (this.network.type === "wifi" || this.network.type === "4g" || this.network.type === "3g" || this.network.type === "2g" || this.network.type === "cellular" || this.network.type === "none") {
            this.showToastService.showToast("Internet connection available!",'success');
            this.WatchConnection();
          }
        }, 3000);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then inject it like so:

*app.component.ts*

```
 constructor(private networkStateService: NetworkStateService,){
   this.initializeApp();
}

  async initializeApp() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();

    if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      this.networkStateService.WatchConnection();
   }
 }
```

Toast service is like so:

show-toast.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastController, Events } from "@ionic/angular";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ShowToastService {
  toast: HTMLIonToastElement;
  constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController,
   ) { }

  async showToast(message: string, color: string): Promise<void> {
const toast: HTMLIonToastElement = await this.toastCtrl.create({
  message,
  duration: 3000,
  position: 'bottom',
  color,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
      }
    }
  ]
});
toast.present();
}
}
```

Comment: i did something like this, but instead of onDisconnected i used the onChange event from network plugin, but no one of then worked for me :c, the toast doesnt show

Comment: I have updated the Toast service too. The above solution is working fine on the Ionic 4 app. Fully tested on Android ad iOS apps.