# show modal when network is offline in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I want to display a modal when the network connection is offline.

i have this working function that says to me when the network is online or offline:

```js
  verifyNetworkConnection() {
    this.networkService.isNetworkConnected
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(connected => {
        if (connected) {
          console.log('Online!');
        } else {
          console.log('Offline!');
          this.screenService.createModal(LostConnectionComponent);
        }
      });
  }
```

when the conncetion is offline, i want to display a modal, but i got this error in my console:

GET http://localhost:8100/0.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

GET http://localhost:8100/164.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

why i cant open a modal when its offline?

this is my create modal function:

```js
  public async createModal(component, componentProps?) {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component,
      componentProps
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Comment: Use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306619/1077309

Comment: lol, i work with this guy, he is literly at my side in that moment